# Add Score Counter for Java GUI Project

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I'm working on a Rock Paper Scissors game that uses java GUI and I have it all working great, but I want to add a score counter for both user and computer that are both in the corner of the screen and 1 is added every time either side wins a game.  I am not doing a best out of 3 or anything like that, it's just an endless game and I want it to add up as you go. Here is my code, the .jpg and .png files are just images I use for the background and other stuff.  I have already attempted at creating a method to keep score (method Score and other stuff related to yourScore and compScore), but I am having trouble displaying it and would welcome any new ideas, although I have been using JLabels for almost everything.

```
public class main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton rock;
    JButton scissors;
    JButton paper;
    JLabel left;
    ImageIcon rock1;
    ImageIcon scissors1;
    ImageIcon scissors2;
    ImageIcon paper2;
    ImageIcon paper1;
    ImageIcon rock2;
    ImageIcon back;
    ImageIcon scissorsb;
    JLabel right;
    String[] RPS = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(RPS.length);
    int yourChoice = -1;
    JTextField texter;
    JLabel winner;
    Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
    SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
    String Tie = "Tie";
    String compwins = "Computer wins!";
    String youwin = "You win!";
    int yourNum = 9;
    JLabel yourScore;
    int compNum = 0;
    JLabel compScore;
    Font winnerFont = new Font("Font", Font.PLAIN, 35);

    public main() {
        super("Rock Paper Scissors");
        back = new ImageIcon("image1233450665506.png");
        paper1 = new ImageIcon("paper1.png");
        paper2 = new ImageIcon("paper2.png");
        scissors1 = new ImageIcon("scissors1.png");
        scissors2 = new ImageIcon("scissors2.png");
        rock1 = new ImageIcon("rock1.png");
        rock2 = new ImageIcon("rock2.png");

        JLabel background = new JLabel(back);
        left = new JLabel();
        right = new JLabel();
        winner = new JLabel();
        yourScore = new JLabel();
        compScore = new JLabel();
        right.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(1280, 985);
        winner.setFont(winnerFont);
        winner.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        yourScore.setFont(winnerFont);
        compScore.setFont(winnerFont);

        contentPane.setLayout(layout);

        contentPane.add(winner);
        contentPane.add(left);
        contentPane.add(right);
        contentPane.add(yourScore);
        contentPane.add(compScore);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, left, 300, SpringLayout.NORTH,
                contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, right, 300,
                SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, right, 0, SpringLayout.EAST,
                contentPane);

        rock = new JButton("Rock");
        paper = new JButton("Paper");
        scissors = new JButton("Scissors");

        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, rock, 500, SpringLayout.WEST,
                contentPane);
        this.add(rock, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, rock, -30, SpringLayout.SOUTH,
                contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, rock, 40, SpringLayout.NORTH,
                contentPane);
        this.add(paper, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, paper, -30,
                SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, paper, 200, SpringLayout.NORTH,
                contentPane);
        this.add(scissors, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, scissors, -30,
                SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, scissors, 360,
                SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
        rock.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        rock.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140, 50));
        paper.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        paper.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140, 50));
        scissors.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        scissors.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140, 50));
        rock.repaint();
        scissors.repaint();
        paper.repaint();
        contentPane.add(background);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        rock.doClick();
        paper.doClick();
        scissors.doClick();
        rock.addActionListener(this);
        paper.addActionListener(this);
        scissors.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        main framer = new main();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (arg0.getSource() == rock) {
            left.setIcon(rock1);
            yourChoice = 0;
        } else if (arg0.getSource() == paper) {
            left.setIcon(paper1);
            yourChoice = 1;
        } else if (arg0.getSource() == scissors) {
            left.setIcon(scissors1);
            yourChoice = 2;
        }

        computerMove();

        // result.repaint();
        Score();
    }

    public void Score() {
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, winner, 50,
                SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, winner, 560, SpringLayout.WEST,
                contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, compScore, 100,
                SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, compScore, 600,
                SpringLayout.EAST, contentPane);
        yourScore = new JLabel(Integer.toString(yourNum));
        compScore = new JLabel(Integer.toString(compNum));

        if (num == 0 && yourChoice == 0) {
            winner.setText(Tie);
            winner.repaint();
        } else if (num == 1 && yourChoice == 0) {
            yourNum++;
            yourScore.repaint();
            winner.setText(compwins);
            winner.repaint();
        } else if (num == 2 && yourChoice == 0) {
            compNum++;
            compScore.repaint();
            winner.setText(youwin);
            winner.repaint();
        } else if (num == 0 && yourChoice == 1) {
            yourNum++;
            yourScore.repaint();
            winner.setText(youwin);
            winner.repaint();
        } else if (num == 1 && yourChoice == 1) {
            winner.setText(Tie);
            winner.repaint();
        } else if (num == 2 && yourChoice == 1) {
            compNum++;
            compScore.repaint();
            winner.setText(compwins);
            winner.repaint();
        } else if (num == 0 && yourChoice == 2) {
            compNum++;
            compScore.repaint();
            winner.setText(compwins);
            winner.repaint();
        } else if (num == 1 && yourChoice == 2) {
            yourNum++;
            yourScore.repaint();
            winner.setText(youwin);
            winner.repaint();
        } else if (num == 2 && yourChoice == 2) {
            winner.setText(Tie);
            winner.repaint();
        }
        winner.repaint();
        yourScore.repaint();
        compScore.repaint();
        yourScore.setForeground(Color.RED);
        compScore.setForeground(Color.RED);
        winner.setForeground(Color.RED);

    }

    public void computerMove() {
        num = rand.nextInt(RPS.length);
        if (num == 0) {
            right.setIcon(rock2);
        } else if (num == 1) {
            right.setIcon(paper2);
        } else if (num == 2) {
            right.setIcon(scissors2);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it would be really easy if you use [Absolute Positioning](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/AbsCoordinate.shtml) which allows you to set the JLabels, JButtons, etc by their coordinates instead of having to position them and make the code super confusing.

Then for the score part I would just create a new JLabel, one for the computer and one for the player, that is displayed in the top left/right and will show the scores.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks! I'll try that out, and I already got the JLabels set up, but I'm having another problem trying to get them to increase every time there is a win, I made yourScore and compScore integer to string of yourNum and compNum, but I don't really know much about how that works and how to handle it, so if you could explain how integer to string works that would be great

Comment: Well if you have a String and want to change it to an integer then try doing: int myScore = Integer.parseInt(myStringScore); where myStringScore is a String.

Comment: ok, I realized that im fine using integer to string, but the problem now is that absolute positioning isnt working for me, when I set the panel layout to null, like in the link you put, nothing shows up, I'm sure I'm supposed to put something else there, but I don't know what that is, and also when i leave that without null, the number ends up adding numbers on to the right of it as i click